# Deriving the mean and variance from probability density functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A random variable $X$ has a probability density function given by:
$$f_X(x) = \frac{2(\theta -x)}{\theta^2}, \ \ \ \ 0<x<\theta $$
Derive the mean and variance for $X$ in terms of $\theta$.

$ $
I'm assuming I should be using the fact that $\mu=\Bbb E 
\left[X\right]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} xf_X(x)dx$ and the fact that $Var\left[X\right]=\Bbb E\left[X^2\right]-\Bbb E\left[X\right]^2$ but when I'm integrating $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} xf_X(x)dx$ I'm finding that it diverges. Is this an error on my part or if my integration is correct how do I proceed from here?

Comment: You probability distribution is valid for $0 < x < \theta$ if it was for $-\infty < x < \infty$ then yes it would not be finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they say $$ f_X(x)  = \frac{2(\theta-x)}{\theta^2},\;\;\;0<x<\theta$$ for a PDF this means that the PDF is zero outside the range $0<x<\theta.$ So although your definition $$ E(X)  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_X(x)dx$$ is correct,when you plug in the PDF you get$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_X(x)dx  = \int_0^\theta \frac{2x(\theta-x)}{\theta^2}dx$$ since $f_X(x)$ is zero outside the interval $(0,\infty).$ This integral does not diverge.

Comment: OK thanks I had my bounds wrong when I was integrating it